# Android ViewPageIndication with intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Today I've found that new library for [pageflipper](http://www.viewpagerindicator.com). But I don't know so far how to enhance this library for using Intent.

What I mean is these examples only mention for display text in body not include another page with intent. Thus I need to know how to include another page (java) with intent in this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Today I've found that new library for pageflipper.

ViewPagerIndicator is for `ViewPager`. There is nothing in Android called "pageflipper".

> Thus I need to know how to include another page (java) with intent in this library.

You don't. Putting activities inside of other activities is officially deprecated by the platform and has nothing to do with `ViewPager`, let alone `ViewPagerIndicator`. Your `ViewPager` can have pages that are Views (i.e., inflated layouts), optionally having those be managed by fragments.

Comment: @ppshein: Change your activities to be fragments.